# BeginResize/EndResize Event for Control on WinForms Design Surface

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, design-surface

**TLDR:** I would like to know how I can create a hook into a begin-resize and an end-resize event for a design-time control instance on the designer surface.

---

**Detail:** Specifically, I am working with a design surface produced by a BasicLoader in the System.Design and System.Component.Design .NET namespaces. Specifically, I'm working a design-time instance of the TableLayoutPanel. That control exposes a **SizeChanged** event and a **Resize** event--alas, both fire *during* the resize operation--that is, *while* the control is being resized--as well as when the resize operation is complete. I therefore have no way of know when the resize operation began and when it officially ended.

One way to tackle this would be to detect a mouse-down event along with a resize event--but it's unclear to me how I can detect a mouse-down event *on any of the grab handles* of a control being resized.

For the records, I revisited the BehaviorService and saw that it exposes **BeginDrag**, **EndDrag**, and **Synchronize**--I see nothing in that service that would help me with BeginResize/EndResize events.

So, ideally, I would like to subscribe to BeginResize/EndResize events for any designer instance of a Winform control, but I would be happy if the provided answer covered only my need to have these events attached to a designer instance of the TableLayoutPanel control...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a resize starts, a designer transaction with a specific description starts and when the design ends, the transaction will be closed.

You can rely on `TransactionOpened` event of the `IDesignerHost` and check the `TransactionDescription` to see if it starts with `"Resize"`, set a flag `resizing` to `true`. Then in `TransactionClosed` you can check if the flag is `true`, it means it's a resize end has happened.

**Example**

Here is a *PoC* to show how it works. Add the following control into a Windows Forms project and after building the project, drop an instance of `MyControl` on the form. Then if you try to resize the form, you will see the `Resize started.` and `Resize ended.` text on title-bar of the form:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyControl : Control
{
    IDesignerHost host;
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if(DesignMode)
        {
            host = (IDesignerHost)Site.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
            host.TransactionOpened += Host_TransactionOpened;
            host.TransactionClosed += Host_TransactionClosed;
        }
    }
    bool resizing = false;
    private void Host_TransactionOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (host?.TransactionDescription?.StartsWith("Resize") == true)
        {
            resizing = true;
            ((Control)host.RootComponent).Text = "Resize Started.";
        }
    }
    private void Host_TransactionClosed(object sender,
        DesignerTransactionCloseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (resizing)
        {
            resizing = false;
            ((Control)host.RootComponent).Text = "Resize ended.";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do some R&D before going with this solution, you may want to take a look at the following classes (mostly internal) in `System.Design` assembly: `GrabHandleGlyph`, `ResizeBehavior`.

Comment: Awesome, splendid, etc., etc., etc. :) Endless thanks.