# Is it possible to attach an event to specific user behavior in designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm developing a **user control consisting of two components** to be used in WinForms. In order to make it convenient for user to adjust the width of both components, I want to implement the following functionality: **when user drag the left boundary to resize the control, the left component changes its size, and the right component resizes when the right boundary is dragged.**
Since both Resize and Move events are fired when the left boundary is dragged, I cannot simply achieve it by adding listeners to the event handlers, thus I'm wondering if there's a way to attach an event to specific user behavior in the designer, like dragging the boundary to resize or move the control.
**If it proves impossible, any solution to solve the problem will also be of great help!** Appreciations in advance.

Comment: If you have seen such functionality in designer, for example in split container, then it means it's possible. without having more context, code, or picture of the component, I cannot imagine what you are trying to do; I'm even not sue if you need design-time support, maybe it's just achievable using dock/anchor/layout, and etc. Anyways, you may find the following post inspiring.

Comment: [BeginResize/EndResize Event for Control on WinForms Design Surface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59947888/3110834)

Comment: [UserControl with header and content - Allow dropping controls in content panel and Prevent dropping controls in header at design time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50772584/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks a lot! I guess split container is exactly what I needed.